# Overriding the WorldDraw method for an AutoCAD GripData crashes AutoCAD

Tags: c#, .net, overriding, autocad, autocad-plugin

I am using the C# .NET API for AutoCAD. I have a derived class for GripData

```
class PanelMidGrips : GripData
{
    private readonly PanelPerimeterLine _line;

    public PanelMidGrips(PanelPerimeterLine line)
    {
        this.GripPoint = line.TranslateToWCS(line.MidPoint);//GripPoint comes from GripData
        _line = line;
    }
}
```

`TranslateToWCS()` shouldn't be important. It takes a point in the OCS of the block and translates it to a point in model space, so the grip point can be rendered correctly in place on the block.

My problem is when I try to override `WorldDraw()` AutoCAD crashes.

```
public override bool WorldDraw(Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface.WorldDraw worldDraw, ObjectId entityId, DrawType type, Point3d? imageGripPoint, double dGripSize)
{
    return base.WorldDraw(worldDraw, entityId, type, imageGripPoint, dGripSize);    
}
```

When I debug with a breakpoint at the return base..... line I can see that the base method runs. But as I continue to step through when the method exits, my AutoCAD freezes  for 10 seconds or so then crashes, with no StackTrace or information given.

Edit 0: I tried adding a try/catch block to see if anything different would happen. But the same thing happens, the base method returns a false and as the method is ending my IDE and AutoCAD freeze and then crash.

```
public override bool WorldDraw(Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface.WorldDraw worldDraw, ObjectId entityId, DrawType type, Point3d? imageGripPoint, double dGripSize)
{
    try
    {
        return base.WorldDraw(worldDraw, entityId, type, imageGripPoint, dGripSize);
    }
    catch(Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime.Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Edit 1: Very strange behavior. When I added an override for `ViewPortDraw()` by itself, no `WorldDraw()` override, there was no crash. No crashes when looking at the block in model space, or through a Viewport. But the grips dont render now.

But when I also added back in the `WorldDraw()` override, with the `ViewportDraw()` override, there was no more crashing! No crashing in model space or through a viewport! But like before the grips are no longer rendering.

And if I remove the override for both of these methods, the grips render as normal??

```
public override bool ViewportDraw(Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface.ViewportDraw worldDraw, ObjectId entityId, DrawType type, Point3d? imageGripPoint, int gripSizeInPixels)
{
    try
        {
            return base.ViewportDraw(worldDraw, entityId, type, imageGripPoint, gripSizeInPixels);
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
}

public override bool WorldDraw(Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface.WorldDraw worldDraw, ObjectId entityId, DrawType type, Point3d? imageGripPoint, double dGripSize)
{
    try
    {
        return base.WorldDraw(worldDraw, entityId, type, imageGripPoint, dGripSize);
    }
    catch (System.Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this help. but one time i met quite similar problem, that time solution was override subWorldDraw instead of WorldDraw. I don't write it as the answer because it's just the idea, from the bottom of my leaky memory, maybe I'm in deep mistake.

Comment: unfortunately @CADDeveloper the GripData class that I am inheriting and overriding doesn't have a subWorldDraw method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it turned out that `WorldDraw()` was not the method I needed to override. I'm not sure what it does at this point. All I know is that `ViewportDraw()` is the method that I needed to override. Once I did that and adjusted the geometry accordingly, everything worked fine.

I figured ViewportDraw() was just for when your looking at the overriden thing through a viewport in paper space, but I guess that is not the case. It works for if you are in Model Space as well.

This is what I used to draw a box as the grip point

```
public override bool ViewportDraw(Autodesk.AutoCAD.GraphicsInterface.ViewportDraw worldDraw, ObjectId entityId, DrawType type, Point3d? imageGripPoint, int gripSizeInPixels)
        {
            try
            {
                Point2d glyphSize = worldDraw.Viewport.GetNumPixelsInUnitSquare(this.GripPoint);
                Double glyphHeight = (gripSizeInPixels / glyphSize.Y);

                Matrix3d e2w = worldDraw.Viewport.EyeToWorldTransform;
                Point3d pt = this.GripPoint.TransformBy(e2w);

                Point3dCollection pnts = new Point3dCollection
                {
                    new Point3d(pt.X - glyphHeight, pt.Y + (glyphHeight), pt.Z),
                    new Point3d(pt.X - glyphHeight, pt.Y - (glyphHeight), pt.Z),
                    new Point3d(pt.X + glyphHeight, pt.Y - (glyphHeight), pt.Z),
                    new Point3d(pt.X + glyphHeight, pt.Y + (glyphHeight), pt.Z),
                    new Point3d(pt.X - glyphHeight, pt.Y + (glyphHeight), pt.Z)
                };

                worldDraw.Geometry.DeviceContextPolygon(pnts);

                return false;
                
            }
            catch
            {
                return base.ViewportDraw(worldDraw, entityId, type, imageGripPoint, gripSizeInPixels);
            }
        }
```